# ranking algorithm base on multiple condition/factor

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I'm writing a mini game but stuck in the end. It's a simple quiz where it rank user by the number of question correctly answered and the time taken to finish the set of questions.

I easily can rank user base on who answered the most question, but how do I calculate who's the best performer base on 2 conditions?

Comment: If two users have the same number of correct answers then the one who finished fastest should be ranked higher. In other words, sort by number of correct answers and then time. In my opinion somebody who was slower but got more questions right should be ranked higher. (Of course, this is a method of ranking a list of users, not of assigning a single score to a single user.)

Comment: give the two conditions a factor (possibly not the same) and multiply then the right answers of the quiz.

Comment: Do all users begin quiz at the same time?

Comment: @nnnnnn it make sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can process several conditions in a single pass in the comparison function of Array.prototype.sort().

Example:

```
var score = [];

storeScore('user1', 7, 65); // 7 correct answers in 65 sec.
storeScore('user2', 8, 70); // 8 correct answers in 70 sec.
storeScore('user3', 6, 50); // 6 correct answers in 50 sec.
storeScore('user4', 7, 50); // 7 correct answers in 50 sec.

score = score.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.correct > a.correct || (b.correct == a.correct && b.time < a.time);
});

for(var id in score) {
  console.log(
    '#' + ((id | 0) + 1),
    score[id].userId,
    score[id].correct + ' correct answers in ' +
    score[id].time + ' seconds'
  );
}

function storeScore(userId, correct, time) {
  score.push({
    userId : userId,
    correct: correct,
    time   : time
  });
}
```

Output:

```
#1 user2 8 correct answers in 70 seconds
#2 user4 7 correct answers in 50 seconds
#3 user1 7 correct answers in 65 seconds
#4 user3 6 correct answers in 50 seconds
```

Comment: nide, multiple sort, why i make stuff complicated, it's so simple

Comment: Glad to help. Note that we're slightly abusing the sort() function here, as we are returning true (interpreted as 1) or false (interpreted as 0). '0' really means 'both values are equal'. A more standard way would be `return b.correct > a.correct || (b.correct == a.correct && b.time < a.time) ? 1 : -1;` (but my original version should work just the same in most if not all versions of ECMAScript).

Comment: Just a note here, it's best to use the proper implementation of sort, returning either 1 or -1, since in many cases this will silently fail (the original, unsorted array will be returned).

Answer (score 0):

Play around with the relative weight of the two conditions.

What I mean is simple. Think of the following equation:

```
weight(user) = a * parameter_1 + b *  parameter_2
```

In your case the parameters are `number_of_correct` answers and `time_spent`, but this is true for any number of parameters (shortest time to answer a single question, number of retries, whatever).

There are no "correct" values to `a` and `b`, only what works for you. I would play around with some different values for them, see how your ranking list ends up and then decide on them.

This is a common question when ranking results of test with multiple data points per test - how do you decide which kind of data point is more important.

*Note:* For two parameters you don't really need two parameters, one is enough (same as saying `a=1`).

Comment: weight is a function in javascript?

Comment: @EuniceChia - It was meant as an equation (and explained as such). The idea that the weight of a user is determined by some combination of the different parameters...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.race()`, `Promise.all()`, `onsubmit` event of `<form>` element

```js
var forms = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("[id^=form]")),
progress = new Date().getTime();

Promise.race(
  forms.map(function(form, index) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
        resolve.call(form, [form.id, new Date().getTime() - progress]);
      });
    })
  })
)
.then(function(res) {
  console.log(res)
  alert(res[0] + " completed quiz fastest at " + res[1])
});

Promise.all(
  forms.map(function(form, index) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
        resolve.call(form, [form.id, new Date().getTime() - progress]);
      });
    })
  })
)
.then(function(quiz) {
  if (quiz[0][1] < quiz[1][1]) {
    alert(quiz[0][0] + " wins quiz")
  } else {
    alert(quiz[1][0] + " wins quiz")
  }
})
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <label>user 1</label>
  5+5=10<input name="correct1" type="checkbox" required>
  5+6=12<input name="incorrect1" type="checkbox" required>
  5+2=7<input name="correct2" type="checkbox" required>
  7+7=15<input name="incorrect2" type="checkbox" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<form id="form2">
  <label>user 2</label>
  5+5=10<input name="correct1" type="checkbox" required>
  5+6=12<input name="incorrect1" type="checkbox" required>
  5+2=7<input name="correct2" type="checkbox" required>
  7+7=15<input name="incorrect2" type="checkbox" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```