# Provide strict ordering during comparison with multiple fields

Tags: c++, algorithm, language-agnostic, boolean-logic

How do you provide strict ordering between objects with a lot of comparable fields?

Assume you have two objects `x` and `y` that you have to compare, each with 3 fields (a, b,c)

```
bool less(x, y)
  return x.a < y.a || x.b < y.b || x.c < y.c
```

Good, but this provide weak ordering. If x.a < y.a and y.b < x.b, `less(x,y)` is true, `less(y, x)` is also true.

I am used to writing

```
bool less(x, y)
  return x.a < y.a || (x.a == y.a && x.b < y.b)
```

but it start being very ugly once the number of fields involved grows.

```
bool less(x, y)
  return x.a < y.a || 
        (x.a == y.a && x.b < y.b) ||
        (x.a == y.a && x.b == y.b && x.c < y.c) ||
        (x.a == y.a && x.b == y.b && x.c == y.c && x.d < y.d);
```

Does someone has a better looking algorithm?

Comment: I think you need to define what is the most important field, and what is less. Ordering should (I think) be determined precisely. Basically, what property do you check first, what is second and what is third?

Comment: I would love to do that but due to the nature of the problem the comparison *must* take account each field some way or another

Comment: Another option is to create a function that does some calculation of the three (or four, or ten) properties that gives you one value and *that* is what you compare. Something like `val_to_compare = 1*a + 10*b + 23*c`. This gives you a way to attach weights to the properties.

Comment: Can you explain the nature of the problem?

Comment: Please look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38196161/ranking-algorithm-base-on-multiple-condition-factor/38197511#38197511

Comment: Is this a question about Java or C++?

Comment: Store the attribute (references / pointers to them) in an array and then use a loop - With correct optimization level, your compiler will unroll it.

Comment: Thanks Holt! great idea!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on C++11 or higher, there is a nice trick to get SWO without having to write it out by hand. You can use `std::tuple`, to pack your members and the fact that `std::tuple` implements `operator<` as a lexicographical ordering.

So you can write this

```
struct foo {
    int x, y, z;

    bool operator<(const foo& rhs) const {
        return std::tie(x, y, z) < std::tie(rhs.x, rhs.y, rhs.y);
    }
};
```

and struct `foo` will be compared lexicographically by x, y, z. This is still a lot to write, so you can improve it a bit

```
struct foo {
    int x, y, z;

    auto tied() const {
        return std::tie(x, y, z);
    }

    bool operator<(const foo& rhs) const {
        return tied() < rhs.tied();
    }
};
```

this can save a lot of typing if you have a lot of members, but it assumes C++14 (for C++11, you have to write out the return type of `tied` by hand).

Comment: Very nice approach. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

I normally do this:

```
bool operator< (type x, type y) {
    if (x.a < y.a) return true;
    if (x.a > y.a) return false;

    if (x.b < y.b) return true;
    if (x.b > y.b) return false;

    return x.c < y.c;
}
```

This provides hard ordering and extends for as many elements as you care without growing overhead per element.